# Angular js - Clone data realtime from one field to another

Tags: angularjs, forms

Trying to figure out form related angular technique. Im new to angularjs and started digging deep into it.

Well im trying to get current and permanent address in a form. When the "same as current" checkbox is checked then value of current address field is written in permanent address field ng-value.

While permanent address field is typed first and then we checked "same as current" not overwriting field from current address ng-value.

Current Address field

```
  <input type="text" class="h-textform form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" name="current_address_line1" ng-model="contacts.current_address_line1" placeholder="House Number">
```

checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="disable" checked="checked" ng-model="sameascurrent">Same as Current
```

Permenent Address :

```
    <input type="text" class="h-textform form-control" ng-if="sameascurrent"  id="exampleInputEmail3" ng-value="contacts.current_address_line1" name="permenent_address_line1" ng-model="contacts.permenent_address_line1" ng-disabled="sameascurrent" placeholder="House Number">
    <input type="text" class="h-textform form-control" ng-if="!sameascurrent"  id="exampleInputEmail3"  name="permenent_address_line1" ng-model="contacts.permenent_address_line1" ng-disabled="sameascurrent" placeholder="House Number">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rX3iT5lX2JEIArvxL8SK?p=preview

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, there is a default checked for 'same as current ' and so i used 'ng-value' to get typing realtime in permanent field.

Answer (score 1):

Move overwriting logic to controller. For permanent address use similar inputs as for current (no `ng-value` only `ng-model`) plus `ng-disabled`.

```
<input type="text" class="h-textform form-control"  id="exampleInputEmail3" name="permenent_address_line1" ng-model="contacts.permenent_address_line1" ng-disabled="sameascurrent" placeholder="House Number">

<input type="text" class="h-textform form-control"  id="exampleInputEmail3"  name="permenent_address_line2" ng-model="contacts.permenent_address_line2" ng-disabled="sameascurrent" placeholder="Street Name">
```

Add `ng-change` to checkbox input:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="change()" value="disable" checked="checked" ng-model="sameascurrent">Same as Current
```

and function called when checkbox is changed in controller. This function overwrites model of permanent address if `sameascurrent` is true.

```
$scope.change = function () {
  if ($scope.sameascurrent) {
      $scope.contacts.permenent_address_line1 = $scope.contacts.current_address_line1;
      $scope.contacts.permenent_address_line2 = $scope.contacts.current_address_line2;
  }
}
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/aEuG62gaUh5U4Xl5ZUTv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="h-textform form-control" ng-if="sameascurrent"  id="exampleInputEmail3" !!ng-value="contacts.current_address_line1"!! name="permenent_address_line1" ng-model="contacts.permenent_address_line1" ng-disabled="sameascurrent" placeholder="House Number">
```

Remove ng-value from input. Ng-value is used to set values like objects to the radio box or smth like this.

UPD: Just remember. When you are using ng-model, this means that value from input will be dynamicly set to the your model. So you can bind it from model to anywhere you wont

Answer (score 0):

`ng-value` just set the filed once, for realtime data clone,you can write your own `$watch` method inside the controller:

```
function sync(){
 if($scope.sameascurrent){
    var contacts = $scope.contacts;
    contacts.permenent_address_line1 = contacts.current_address_line1;
    contacts.permenent_address_line2 = contacts.current_address_line2;
 }
}
$scope.$watch('contacts',sync,true);
$scope.$watch('sameascurrent',sync);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EPoprBLeNxlwDlklWuiC?p=preview

For more detail on `$watch`, you can refer [angular docs for $scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)